# how to change column width inside datalist control in asp.net

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, datalist

I have a `datalist` control in which data is shown in 3 `<td>` as shown in `html`.

```
 <asp:DataList ID="DataList1" runat="server" 
    onitemdatabound="DataList1_ItemDataBound" Width="400px">
<ItemTemplate>
<table style="width: 130px"><tr><td style="width:65px;">
    <asp:Image ID="Image1" runat="server" Width="59px" Height="60px" 
        ImageUrl='<%# "~/User/UserPic/" + Eval("reg_pic") %>' /></td>
    <td style="width:162px;" class="wdth150">
        <asp:Label
        ID="lbl_nam" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("reg_nam") %>' ForeColor="White"></asp:Label><br />
        <asp:Label ID="lbl_ad" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("reg_age") %>' 
            ForeColor="White"></asp:Label>
        </td><td style="width:109px" class="wdth120"></td><td>
            <asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton2" runat="server">Proceed</asp:LinkButton></td></tr>
        </table>
</ItemTemplate>
</asp:DataList>
```

My problem is that these records are appear very closely i want to show some gap between them i tried to use `style="width:120px"` but that didn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably need to set [**padding**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/padding) in class or style to put space at the end of columns

```
padding:5px;
```

> The padding CSS property sets the required padding space on all sides
>   of an element. The padding area is the space between the content of
>   the element and its border. Negative values are not allowed.
>
> The padding property is a shorthand to avoid setting each side
>   separately (padding-top, padding-right, padding-bottom, padding-left), [reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/padding).

Comment: thanks for answering, what should i do if i want 10px gap in first two  <td> and 40px in last

Comment: You can make two classes and assign them on ItemDataBound event, http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.datalist.itemdatabound.aspx

Comment: Thanks adil I got that

Answer (score 1):

use

```
<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
```

and try to give width in `percentage` instead of `Pixels`...